# Active Storage service for Action Text attachments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, actiontext

Rails 6.1 added support for multiple Action Storage services. It is now possible to assign different services to attributes.

```
has_one_attached :image_1, service: :aws
has_one_attached :image_2, service: :gcloud
```

Action Text uses default Action Storage service for storing files. Is there a possibility to provide a different Action Storage service to Action Text?